# File reader and Writer in Java

Tags: java, file, text-files

Hey guys have a very basic question in Files writing in java. I want to write a long value to a file using FileWriter.write() function but it gives error. Here is the code

```
accountNos[i] = bA[i].getAccountNo();
fw.write(accountNos[i]);
```

Error: change accountNos[i] to int.

But if I change it then it would mean a loss of information and I tried converting it String but it says it cannot convert primitive type long to string. I did:
    fw.write(accountNos[i].toString());

Please help guys...

Comment: So what do you want? Int or String?

Comment: accountNos[i] = bA[i].getAccountNo();
We don't know what any of those are.

Comment: @codethulhu I'd assume a long array at left and `getAccountNo()` is a long array,

Comment: @hexafraction I would assume as much as well, but I shouldn't have to, and I won't. If a user can't bother to ask a quality question, I'm not going to waste my time guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Long.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long%29):

```
fw.write(Long.toString(accountNos[i]));
```

Edit: It looks like `accountNos` is declared as `int[]`. Change it to be declared as `long[]`.

Comment: No its declaration is as follows: long accountNos[] = new long[3];

Comment: just one more thing so when I read from the file do I need to convert it back to long or it stores account nos as long only and while reading also gives long??

Comment: Actually I guess all files when readed give data in String format only and you need to convert it to long